# How to get max closed date and status for the below input dataset in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a below spark dataframe and I need to check if the job is closed or not. Each job can have sub jobs and a job is considered as closed once all subjobs are closed.
Please can you advise the way to achieve this in pyspark.

For example: input df

```
JobNum   CloseDt      ClosedFlg
12                    N
12-01    2012-01-01   Y
12-02    2012-02-01   Y
13       2013-01-01   Y
14       
14-01    2015-01-02   Y
14-02                 N
```

Output_df:

```
JobNum    IsClosedFlg   Max_ClosedDt
12        Y             2012-02-01
13        Y             2013-01-01
14        N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a row number partitioned by the jobnum and ordered by the sub-jobnum in descending order, and filter the rows with row number = 1.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy(F.split('JobNum', '-')[0])
              .orderBy(F.split('JobNum', '-')[1].desc())
    )
).filter('rn = 1').select(
    F.split('JobNum', '-')[0].alias('JobNum'), 
    F.col('ClosedFlg').alias('IsClosedFlg'), 
    F.col('CloseDt').alias('Max_ClosedDt')
)

df2.show()
+------+-----------+------------+
|JobNum|IsClosedFlg|Max_ClosedDt|
+------+-----------+------------+
|    12|          Y|  2012-02-01|
|    13|          Y|  2013-01-01|
|    14|          N|        null|
+------+-----------+------------+
```